# MySql Query - Finding out the Intersect

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, `user_tag, article_tag, article_ignored`. I want to fetch only those articles of `user_id` = 48 for which at least one article tags matches with user tag. I am stuck in this since long time and don't have any idea how to achieve this.

The table structure is as follows:

```
article_ignored table
id | user_id 
1  | 48
2  | 48
3  | 48

article_tag table
id | article_id | tag_id 
1  |    1   |   1  
2  |    1   |   5
3  |    1   |   7
4  |    2   |   2
5  |    2   |   8
6  |    3   |   3
7  |    3   |   2

user_tag table
id | user_id | tag_id
1  |   48    |   2
2  |   48    |   3
```

Required output:

```
article_ignored
id
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, user_id
FROM article_ignored AS ai
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM article_tag AS at
              JOIN user_tag AS ut ON at.tag_id = ut.tag_id
              WHERE ai.id = at.article_id)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dcc51/1)